# urllib error of Google App Engine & python.[Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib

Thanks for your help in advance!

I want to get contents of a website, so I use `urllib.urlopen(url)`.

```
set url='http://localhost:8080'(tomcat page)
```

If I use Google App Engine Launcher, run the application, browse `http://localhost:8082` , it works well.
But if I specify the address and port for the application:

```
python `"D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py" -p 8082 -a 10.96.72.213 D:\pagedemon\videoareademo`
```

there's something wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\_webapp25.py", line 701, in __call__
  handler.get(*groups)
File "D:\pagedemon\videoareademo\home.py", line 76, in get
  wp = urllib.urlopen(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 84, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 205, in open
  return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 343, in open_http
  errcode, errmsg, headers = h.getreply()
File "D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\dist\httplib.py", line 334, in getreply
  response = self._conn.getresponse()
File "D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\dist\httplib.py", line 222, in getresponse
  deadline=self.timeout)
File "D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\urlfetch.py", line 263, in fetch
  return rpc.get_result()
File "D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 592, in get_result
  return self.__get_result_hook(self)
File "D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\urlfetch.py", line 365, in _get_fetch_result
  raise DownloadError(str(err))
DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2 [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed
```

The strangest thing is when I change the url form "`http://localhost:8080`" to "`http://127.0.0.1:8080`", it works well!

I googled a lot, but I didn't find any good solutions.Hoping for some help!
Also, I didn't configure any **proxy.IE** works well.

Answer (score 1):

Your system doesn't necessarily know that localhost should resolve to 127.0.0.1. You might need to put an entry into your hosts file. On Windows, it's located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: Thanks for your help!But why the application can work well which I start with Google App Engine Launcher? My system must know localhost should resolve 127.0.0.1,otherwise browse http://localhost:8080 in IE wouldn't showout tomcat page.Am I right?